# Scaffolding - rails generate - data migrate def in class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scaffolding, self

I'm new to Rails - I started a new rails app `rails new test`, then `rails generate scaffold Name column1:datatype column2:datatype`

In the tutorial once I open the `12345678timestamp_create_names.rb` file I have `def change`, but the tutorial has both `def self.up` and `def self.down`

Why is that? And what is the difference? And should I edit my app now? And in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

migrations has changed from rails2 to rails3, now rails3 is smart enough to understand how it should response with your command

So, consider `change` as a combination of `up` and `down`

if you say

`rake db:migrate` it will consider it as `up`

`rake db:rollback` it will consider it as `down`

[read more here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3.1 introduced the new change method to migrations.

[See Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#anatomy-of-a-migration)

> Rails 3.1 makes migrations smarter by providing a new change method.
>   This method is preferred for writing constructive migrations (adding
>   columns or tables). The migration knows how to migrate your database
>   and reverse it when the migration is rolled back without the need to
>   write a separate down method.

Thus your tutorial probably covers Rails 3.0 but not Rails 2 because you have already used the Rails 3 command for creating a new app.